# Magento 2: After unhold order , order status empty

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.2

If set order status **Hold** programmatically and if i am trying to unhold From Admin Then order status empty. 
https://prnt.sc/k2g1ak
Here is my code for set Hold order status:

```
$orderState = Order::STATE_HOLDED;
$order->setState($orderState)->save();
if($order->canHold()) {
       $order->hold()->save();
}
```

Is there any another way for set order status as **hold**? what am I doing wrong? and why order status empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found correct way for set order status **HOLD**

```
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order;

class Hold extends \Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order
{
    /**
     * Authorization level of a basic admin session
     *
     * @see _isAllowed()
     */
    const ADMIN_RESOURCE = 'Magento_Sales::hold';

    /**
     * Hold order
     *
     * @return \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Redirect
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
        if (!$this->isValidPostRequest()) {
            $this->messageManager->addError(__('You have not put the order on hold.'));
            return $resultRedirect->setPath('sales/*/');
        }
        $order = $this->_initOrder();
        if ($order) {
            try {
                $this->orderManagement->hold($order->getEntityId());
                $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('You put the order on hold.'));
            } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
                $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $this->messageManager->addError(__('You have not put the order on hold.'));
            }
            $resultRedirect->setPath('sales/order/view', ['order_id' => $order->getId()]);
            return $resultRedirect;
        }
        $resultRedirect->setPath('sales/*/');
        return $resultRedirect;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to set the state of the order. Setting the state will cause the problem you're seeing. The following will work when using OrderRepositoryInterface.

```
if($order->canHold()) {
   $order->hold()->save();
}
```